# How can we have time stamp display in BDD story file output

Tags: selenium, bdd, jbehave

I have BDD story file in which i have "given,when,then,scenarios". 
I would like to add timestamp in story file output. How can we do that?

An example:

```
Given a step that is executed before each story

Scope: SCENARIO
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
```

This comes as the output when I run the story via Jenkins. I want to get the timestamp in the story file output as:

```
<Timestamp here> Given a step that is executed before each story

Scope: SCENARIO
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
```

Comment: You mean when you download something the downloaded file name  or the result file?

Comment: No, i mean like in below example
 
'Given a step that is executed before each story1`
`Scope: SCENARIO`
`Given a step that is executed before each scenario`

this comes as output when i run the story via jenkins. 
I want to get timestamp in story file output as 

`"Tmestamp here"`
`Given a step that is executed before each story`
`Scope: SCENARIO`
`Given a step that is executed before each scenario`

Comment: I still have no clue as to what you're asking for.

Comment: @eddieB You did give us an example; it was just hard to parse. I tried to copy your comment into your original problem. Did I understand it correctly? If not please edit it accordingly.

Comment: @Lunivore yes that's exactly what i am looking for..

Comment: @eddieB Fantastic, I don't have an answer for you but have upvoted this because it would be nice to have one. You could also try the jbehave-user mailing list: https://jbehave.org/mailing-lists.html